# Stop a javascript function after a certain time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm facing quite the challenge here, and since i'm new to web development i don't really know where to look.

On this website i'm working on, we are loading a map via a javascript function:

```
initializeMap();
```

This function is called inside:

```
$(document).on("ready", function() {
})
```

Sometimes this function "initializeMap();" takes a long time to run, most likely because i'm getting information from another server, and it might timeout if you have a slow connection, or for any other arbitrary reason.

Is there a way to say, if "initializeMap();" has not completed within 30 seconds, i would like to throw an error (Or console.log for an example).

I have searched a lot, and "Promise.race" seems to be able to do it, but this system requires old browser support, and we can't really update the node.js on the server, so i'm stuck to ES5.

I hope there are some kind people who can point me in the correct direction.

ps. we use jQuery also (Version 3.1)

Comment: You can polyfill `Promise`, this is MDN's recommended polyfilly - https://github.com/stefanpenner/es6-promise

Comment: If you're using jQuery `$.ajax` to get the data, you can use the `timeout` property to set a maximum time to wait for the request. If exceeded it'll trigger the `error` event handler.

Comment: What do you mean by "old browser support"?

Comment: Most likely `initializeMap()` itself is completing quite quickly: It's the callback functions defined inside of it which are not being completed (or even invoked) in a reasonable amount of time. You could set a separate callback on a timeout to perform some fallback tasks if the other callbacks haven't completed after a certain amount of time.

Comment: Does `initializeMap()` return a `Promise`?

Comment: By old browser support i mean I can't know if the users of the system use IE8. It is likely that they use something old.

And no. Initialize map does not return a promise. 
Initialize map, has a lot of subfunction calls.

I will look at the polyfill Promise. Thanks

Comment: How do you determine when `initializeMap()` has "completed"? Why would an individual be using ie8?

Comment: Hmm. I will have to return with how i can determine when it's completed. I'm not infront of the code before later. Many people in the puplic workspace use vastly outdated software. Atleast here in denmark.

Comment: Would it be possible to create a bool value that is being set to true at the end of the initializemap function and then run a counter funtion on a seperate thread that checks the bool val after a set amount of time ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found another solution.

I used `setTimeout` to check for a loading animation after 30 seconds.
If the loading animation is still there, i display an error where the user is able to reload the page.